# (Verification) Greatest element is Maximal Element in Partially Ordered Set.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

**Claim**

Greatest element is Maximal Element in Partially Ordered Set.

**Proof**

Let $(P, \le)$ be a partially ordered set P.

Let $x$ be the greatest element in $(P, \le)$

$x \in P$ is greatest element if and only if $y\le x$ for each $y \in P $

Then $\forall y\in P$ if $x\le y$, $x=y$ since  $y\le x$ and $ x\le y$, which implies that

$x$ is maximal element.

Comment: It's fine, but be careful when writing things like "for $\forall y\in P$"... you really wanted "Then if $x\subset y$ for ANY $y\in P$, then..." or "$\forall y\in P$ if $x\subset y$, then..."

Comment: @luka5z modified it into "each" is it legit?

Comment: Nope.Actually, it's the same. Order does matter. It should be rather: "$\forall y\in P$ if $x\subset y$, then $x=y$..."

Comment: $\exists x \forall y$ is not the same as $\forall y \exists x$

Comment: @luka5z I understand but little confusing about the predicating order of case of OP.. are they conveying different meaning?

Comment: @luka5z is it might be because my statement using two duplicated 'for? such as (1)for \(2)forall y

Comment: No, it conveys another meaning.

Comment: You wrote IF $x\subset y$ FOR ALL $y$, then something. This way you assume $x$ to be a minimal element...

Comment: @luka5z it is.. edited.

Comment: You want to have FOR ALL $y$ IF $x \subset y$ then something. You cocrected it, but it's still not the peroper order. "For all" should be before "If" (before implication)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea is OK, writeup could be stricter: suppose that $x$ is the greatest element of $(P, \le)$. Then suppose $x \le y$ for some $y \in P$, we need to show $y = x$ (this is the definition of being a maximal element). By $x$  being the maximum element, we know already $y \le x$. But in a PO: $x \le y$ and $y \le x$ implies $y=x$  and we are done.

Comment: one more miscellaneous question: would it be different to denote order with notation mark $\le$ from $\subset$?

Comment: No. I find $\subset$ confusing as it often implies a strict order, like $<$ does, I prefer $\le$ for all partial orders.

Comment: understand. has edited the PO.

Comment: @jackerysmith your messing up the quantors. Not $\forall y \in P x \le y$. That would say it's minimal

Comment: corrected it. Put forall at the front , then if ~